# JavaScript Behaviors no longer work when I save my bootstrap .html file into a .cfm file

Tags: html, coldfusion, bootstrap-4

I’m a Coldfusion web developer. I recently began doing front-end design work with Dream Weaver and bootstrap. Whenever i export my bootstrap project into a standard html package and the
Convert some of my pages in to adobe coldfusion’s .cfm files the JavaScript Behaviors no longer work. If I convert the .cfm page back to regular html, then the JavaScript behavior portion of the site works again. Is there a work around in the coding to have JavaScript behaviors to work the same in .cfm files.

Comment: Can you share an example of some code that stops working? What version of ColdFusion are you running?

Comment: And OP, but I'd recommend using another IDE, like VS Code or something. In 20 years of dev, I have pretty much always had strange issues when I've used Dreamweaver that are usually tracked back to Dreamweaver doing some weird formatting or code-completing. Or the wonky internal code that it injects into a page to do the Dreamweaver-y things.

Comment: Open the .cfm file in a browser and press F12.  Click on the console tab.  Then reload the page in the browser.  JavaScript errors that are on the page will appear in the console tab.